# (Proof verification) $\sigma(X)$ is a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{F}.$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and define a random variable $X: \mathcal{F}:\to \mathbb{R}.$ I want to show that the $\sigma$-field $\sigma(X)$ generated by $X$ is indeed a $\sigma$-field, and $\sigma(X) \subset \mathcal{F}.$

I'll first show that $\sigma(X) \subset \mathcal{F}.$ Choose an $A \in \sigma(X):$
$$
A = \lbrace X \in B \rbrace \in \sigma(X)
$$
for some Borel set $B$. By definition of a random variable, $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. This means $\lbrace X \in B \rbrace \in \mathcal{F}$ for all Borel sets $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Thus $A \in \mathcal{F}$ which implies $\sigma(X) \subset \mathcal{F}.$

To show that $\sigma(X)$ is a $\sigma$-field, I have to show: (a) $\varnothing \in \sigma(X),$ (b) $A \in \sigma(X) \implies A^c \in \sigma(X)$, and (c) if $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of sets in $\sigma(X)$ then 
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \sigma(X).
$$
(a) Since $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a $\sigma$-field, $\varnothing \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$ 
Choose $B = \varnothing.$ Then 
$$
\lbrace X \in \varnothing \rbrace = X^{-1}(\varnothing) = \varnothing \in \sigma(X).
$$
(b) Let $A \in \sigma(X).$ Then $A = \lbrace X \in B \rbrace$ for some $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$ Since $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a $\sigma$-field, $B^c \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. The set $A^c$ is the set 
$$
A^c = \lbrace \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in B^c \rbrace = \{ X \in B^c \},
$$
and since $B^c \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),$ $\lbrace X \in B^c \rbrace \in \sigma(X).$

(c) Suppose $(A_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $\sigma(X).$ Then for each $n$,
$$
A_n = \lbrace X \in B_n \rbrace
$$
for some $B_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$ Since $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a $\sigma$-field and $B_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),$ we must have that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$

I claim that 
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \left\lbrace X \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \right\rbrace.
$$
Pick $\omega \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n.$ Then $\omega \in \lbrace X \in B_n \rbrace$ for some $n,$ implying $X(\omega) \in B_n$ for some $n$: 
$$
X(\omega) \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n. 
$$
Thus $\omega \in \lbrace \omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \rbrace = \lbrace X \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \rbrace$.

Now take $\omega \in \lbrace X \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \rbrace.$ Then $X(\omega) \in B_n$ for some $n$. So $\omega \in \lbrace X \in B_n \rbrace \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n.$

Therefore the equality claim is proven. Since $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$ is a Borel set, 
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \left\lbrace X \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \right\rbrace \in \sigma(X).
$$

Comment: Your proof is correct.